# Horizontal Scrolling when click on link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I create a webpage which is scroll horizontal from 
http://www.pixxelfactory.net/jInvertScroll/

but now i am create a menu bar when i am click on menu bar the i will scroll left to div 
my code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>The Hot Air Balloon</title>
    <!--<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jInvertScroll.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" >
      function changeonhover(a)
      {



        for(var i =1 ;i<=4;i++)
        {
          if(i==a)
          {
            document.getElementById("link"+i).style.color = "blue";

          }
          else
          {
            document.getElementById("link"+i).style.color = "white";

          }

        }
      }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      #header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 500;
        height: 45px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <a href="#div1"  id="link1"  >Div1 </a>
      <a href="#div2" id="link2" >Div2 </a>
      <a href="#div3" id="link3" >Div3 </a>
      <a href="#div4" id="link4" >Div4 </a>

    </div>
    <div class="container">

      <!--<div class="horizon scroll">
<img src="images/background.png" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="middle scroll">
<img src="images/cloudsandballoons.png" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="panel1">
-->

      <div class="front scroll">
        <h1 class="intro">Scroll down</h1>

        <div id="div1" onmouseover="changeonhover('1')" class="panel1 page">
          <h2>The Hot Air Balloon</h2>
          <p>
            The hot air balloon is the oldest successful human-carrying flight technology. It is part of a class of aircraft known as balloon aircraft.
          </p>
          <p>
            On November 21, 1783, in Paris, France, the first untethered manned flight was performed by Jean-François Pilâtre de Rozier and François Laurent d'Arlandes in a hot air balloon created on December 14, 1782 by the Montgolfier brothers. Hot air balloons that can be propelled through the air rather than just being pushed along by the wind are known as airships or, more specifically, thermal airships.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div id="div2" onmouseover="changeonhover('2')" class="panel2 page">
          <h2>How they work</h2> 
          <p>A hot air balloon consists of a bag called the envelope that is capable of containing heated air. Suspended beneath is a gondola or wicker basket (in some long-distance or high-altitude balloons, a capsule), which carries passengers and (usually) a source of heat, in most cases an open flame. 
          </p>
          <p>
            The heated air inside the envelope makes it buoyant since it has a lower density than the relatively cold air outside the envelope. 
          </p>
        </div>

        <div id="div3" onmouseover="changeonhover('3')" class="panel3 page">
          <h2>Practicalities</h2>
          <p>As with all aircraft, hot air balloons cannot fly beyond the atmosphere. Unlike gas balloons, the envelope does not have to be sealed at the bottom since the air near the bottom of the envelope is at the same pressure as the air surrounding. 
          </p>
          <p>
            For modern sport balloons the envelope is generally made from nylon fabric and the inlet of the balloon (closest to the burner flame) is made from fire resistant material such as <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomex">Nomex</a>. </p>
        </div>

        <div id="div4" onmouseover="changeonhover('4')" class="panel4 page">
          <h2>Modern ballooning</h2>
          <p>
            Beginning during the mid-1970s, balloon envelopes have been made in all kinds of shapes, such as rocket ships and the shapes of various commercial products, though the traditional shape remains popular for most non-commercial, and many commercial, applications.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.pixxelfactory.net/jInvertScroll/js/jquery.jInvertScroll.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
          $.jInvertScroll(['.scroll']);
        }(jQuery));

      </script>

      <script  type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var target = this.hash,
              $target = $(target);

            $('html, body').stop().animate({
              'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
            }, 900, 'swing', function () {
              window.location.hash = target;
            });
          });
        });
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

but when i click on link i does not work. please help me

[Link](http://darf.t15.org//)

Comment: what do you want to say?

Comment: when i am click on link this will animate but not go to div ..

Comment: you want a horizontal webpage? that shows the page content on click? you might need to have the page contents in divs and hide them via CSS..then when clicking the menu options, show them through jquery

Comment: yes when i click on link

Comment: no i want scrolling not show or hide

Comment: can you show an example(another webpage) of what you want? From what you say, it is difficult to figure out what you want.

Comment: ohky 

u can see there is horizonatal scrolling web page .. which is divided in div .. which is div1 div2 div3 and div4 .. i want when i am click on link1 then page will scroll to div1 ..as for all ..

Comment: In your fiddle, you should put your CSS code in the CSS section and not a link to style.css, so people can see your whole CSS code.

Comment: http://www.pixxelfactory.net/jInvertScroll/css/style.css my CSS link

Comment: http://darf.t15.org/  You can check Here whole page

Comment: please help me out @chipChocolate.py

Comment: Well, I would rather do this using 2d transform matrix, its a lot easier and gives you exactly what you are trying to do. If you want me to put the code together to make it work with 2d transform matrix, I can help.

Comment: yes i want only result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change this

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
}, 900, 'swing', function () {
window.location.hash = target;
});
```

To this (you want the top value to change to the left position value. So scrollTop and position().left

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
'scrollTop': $target.position().left
}, 900, 'swing', function () {
window.location.hash = target;
});
```

Comment: I updated my answer to scrollTop and position().left instead of offset()

Answer (score 0):

On your fiddle, the content div are all on the same "position" so when you click on the links it will not do anything because every div are already on sight.

Instead of trying to use the internal link which are normally used for vertically scrolling, would you mind trying to call your JinvertScroll function on Click on the div links with a parameter of the width from the internal div?

Comment: darf.t15.org You can check Here whole page

Comment: It's similar. Try to use Firebug and select div2, 3 or 4. They are all on sight. Have you tried to use your Invertscroll Plugin?